# Filling in table rows using Jquery .html method

Tags: jquery, html

In table

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover universal" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

        <tbody>
            <span id="appointment_info">
                <tr>
                <td>loading...</td>
                </tr>
            </span>
            <tr>
                <td>12:30 pm</td>
                <td>Jenny Harris</td>
                <td>Exam Room 1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am replacing `span id="appointment_info"` using `jQuery`'s `.html()` method.

Like below.

```
var html_str = "";
var apmts_len = apmts.length > 5 ? 5 : apmts.length;

for (var i = 0; i < apmts_len; ++i) {
    html_str += "<tr> ";
    var info = apmts[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        html_str = html_str + "<td>" + info[j] + "</td> ";
    }
    html_str += "</tr> ";
```

console.log(html_str);
    }

However, this failed. It prints everything in a row in one column, in an ugly format.

The generated `html_str` looks like `<tr> <td>09:00 AM</td> <td>Richard Schwarm</td> <td>7</td> </tr>`

How can I fix this?

Comment: your html is invalid... `tbody` can't have `span` as its child

Comment: That's helpful. What would you suggest then?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the line break formatting is.  The browser does not care what white space you put in your html strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid... `tbody` can't have `span` as its child, there is no need to use a `span` instead you can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) like

```js
var apmts = [
  [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
  [2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
  [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]
]

var html_str = "";
var apmts_len = apmts.length > 5 ? 5 : apmts.length;

for (var i = 0; i < apmts_len; ++i) {
  html_str += "<tr> ";
  var info = apmts[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    html_str = html_str + "<td>" + info[j] + "</td> ";
  }
  html_str += "</tr> ";
}

$('#appointment_info').replaceWith(html_str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover universal" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="appointment_info">
      <td>loading...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12:30 pm</td>
      <td>Jenny Harris</td>
      <td>Exam Room 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another option is to use a separate tbody to hold the dynamic content and assign the `id` to that `tbody` and set its content using `.html()`

```js
var apmts = [
  [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
  [2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
  [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]
]

var html_str = "";
var apmts_len = apmts.length > 5 ? 5 : apmts.length;

for (var i = 0; i < apmts_len; ++i) {
  html_str += "<tr> ";
  var info = apmts[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    html_str = html_str + "<td>" + info[j] + "</td> ";
  }
  html_str += "</tr> ";
}

$('#appointment_info').html(html_str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover universal" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <tbody id="appointment_info">
    <tr>
      <td>loading...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12:30 pm</td>
      <td>Jenny Harris</td>
      <td>Exam Room 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is, there are multiple rows, and thus multiple `<tr> ... </tr>` tags

Comment: Oh then I could assign `id` to `<tbody>`?